# How to print all rows containing a part of input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, sequence

I have a csv file that contains sequence and gene name. I want to take an input from user and print all the rows that contains user input as a part. As an example my data is;

```
Gene 1    ATGCGGTCTA
Gene 2    ACGCCCATGA
Gene 3    TCGAC
```

When user enters GC the outcome must be

```
Gene 1   ATGCGGTCTA 
Gene 2   ACGCCCATGA
```

since both has GC in the sequences.

So far I try;

```
import csv
import sys
import pandas as pd
csv_file = csv.reader(open('DATA.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")
z=input('what would you like to search?').lower()
if z=='sequence':
 s=input('Enter sequence : ').upper()
 df = pd.read_csv('DATA.csv')
 a = list(df['seq'])
 b = ' '.join(str(s) for s in a)
 c= b.find(s)
```

Comment: You mix 2 distinct methods to deal with CSV, the pure Python method and the pandas method. You can remove pandas and iterate over the lines of `csv_file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas` and assuming the column of your dataframe with the sequences is called `sequences`, you can do :
`filtered_df = df[df['sequences'].str.contains(s)]`